# Adding an removing relation between state

Tags: alloy

I have this Alloy Model

```
module Test
sig B {}

sig A {
c: some B,
delta: c lone -> lone c
}


pred operationA[disj x, x': A,  
c1, c2: B]{
x'.delta = x.delta + (c1->c2)
x'.delta = x'.delta - (c1->c2)
x'.c = x.c
} 

run operationA for 10 but 2 A
```

this does not generate me any instance. i am adding relation c1->c2 in x' state and removing it again, some reason it does not allow me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alloy language is declarative, meaning that you write a specification of *what* has to happen in the end and not *how* to make it happen (which is the imperative approach). Therefore, the body of your `operationA` predicate is interpreted as a conjunction of the three lines you wrote there, and not as a sequence of operations to be performed.

More concretely, the line `x'.delta = x'.delta - (c1->c2)` says that the content of the `x'.delta` relation is *at the same time* equal to `x'.delta - c1->c2`.  On it's own, that line is satisfiable if and only if `x'.delta` does not contain tuple `c1->c2` (because the `-` operator is a set difference, and if you try to remove from a set something that's not already in there, the result is the same set).  However, the previous line, `x'.delta = x.delta + (c1->c2)` says that the content of `x'.delta` must include `c1->c2` (plus whatever is in `x.delta`, so those two lines together are unsatisfiable.

If you want to model three steps of an imperative algorithm, you'll have to use three variable, e.g., `x`, `x'`, and `x''`.